# React Native expo ios app download to my iphone without publishing it

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Hey I have developed some simple ios app for my personal use and now I want to have it on my IPhone.

I know that it is possible to test the my app through Expo Go, but I want to have it without keeping it running at terminal.

Also, I would like to avoid paying 99$ for apple developer account because....

Didn't thought that such an obvious action is so difficult to accomplish. So what's the options?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "download" the app, you can install it in `release mode` directly from Xcode.

On Xcode, tap on your `target`'s name at the top of the screen (on the left side of where you select the simulator/device), then tap `"Manage Schemes"`.

From the given list, find the scheme for your target, `select it`, tap the `...` button at the bottom left and tap `duplicate`.

A new screen will pop up. On the `Run` tab (usually the default tab), change `Build Configuration` to `Release`. Change the name (top of the screen) to `YourProject Release` or something similar.

Close the popups, and select that scheme before running your app. You will have a Release version installed on your iPhone.

It probably won't last forever, but you can re-run it once in a while to keep using it and you won't need the terminal attached.

When you want to go back to testing your app (attached to terminal), just go back the `Debug` scheme (the original one).